# Ho to check radio button inside label with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I want to check radio buttons contained in a div based on their parent ID, they set a variable that's used in a function but I can't select them.

```
<label id="radio-step-1" class="btn btn-radio mx-auto" onclick="step=1;">
  <input type="radio" autocomplete="off">one
</label>
<label id="radio-step-2" class="btn btn-radio mx-auto" onclick="step=2;">
  <input type="radio" autocomplete="off">two
</label>
```

---

```
function setStep(){
  document.querySelector("radio-step-" + step "input[type=radio]").checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there is no `div`, Do you want to check the `label` instead of div.? You have to add `#` to select the id, and make the proper concatenation

```
  document.querySelector("#radio-step-" + step+" input[type=radio]").checked = true;
```